# WebSocket or Periodic Requests in hybrid Apps?

Tags: node.js, websocket, request, settimeout

I am developing an hybrid mobile app that collects some user info in background while the user is calling (just during a phone call). Then I have an admin dashboard on a website, where the admins can monitor the (almost) real-time status of the mobile users. To do this, my mobile app must send info to the server. Right now I just use:

`setInterval(sendData, 5000)` to send data each 5sec from the mobile app to the server.
`setInterval(refreshData, 5000)` to request the current status from the admin dashboard to the server.
I don't need a "strong real-time", so it's enough update each 5secs.

Anyway I'd like to know if it's better use web sockets among the mobile app and the server, since the app should send data very often during the day.

Thank you

Comment: Do you realize that you can't use data during a phone call on some networks and some phones?  You are more likely to be able to do simultaneous voice and data on ATT, less likely on Verizon though there are some configurations on Verizon where you can, but not all and perhaps not by default on many phones.

Comment: In general a webSocket or socket.io (which is built on top of a webSocket) connection will be more efficient (less overall data transmissions) for regular data transmissions.  I presume you know that sending data every 5s over a long period of time is going to drain significant battery on a mobile device.

Comment: that's new to me! I didn't know... many thanks for the info.  I live in Italy, and here it seems possible. My app is working. I have to check with other operators. Anyway I'd like an answer to my question, just to know which solution is better.

Comment: Simultaneous data and voice definitely depends upon operator and on newness of phones (3G, 4G, LTE, etc...).  Perhaps not so much of an issue where you are (I really don't know).

Comment: If that is the case, I guess (hope) that the phone will send data to the server as soon the phone call ends. Am I wrong?

Comment: A socket.io connection will probably queue the data and send it when connected again.  A webSocket connection will probably just return an error and it would be up to you to send it again.  But, in both cases, you'd have to test to be sure how it behaves.